# VPN between two nodes of a cluster

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kubectl

I have three nodes, a master which is geographically located elsewhere, and the two other nodes that are close, but not on the same network. I've create a cluster with those three, and now, I want to make a tunnel between the two (close) nodes to compare the benefits to communicate without going to the master, and then come back.

I've search a little, and found out these charts:
https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/openvpn.

Can I use it to create the VPN between the 2 workers nodes?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is not a good idea to use a helm chart for a VPN if you are trying to use it for the kubernetes internal communications.

My advice is to configure the VPN on the nodes itself but that comes with more problems of automation and availability.

What is the main idea of having that setup, can you use some external VPN service instead of installing inside the cluster? have you tried with peering instead of VPN?

Some actual cloud providers allow you to have easy turnkey clusters, have you tried it?

**UPDATE**

As per comments maybe two more solutions are good ones by itself or in combination:

- Istio https://istio.io/
- gRPC https://grpc.io/ in conjunction of mTLS

Comment: I would not use it for the Kubernetes internal communications, but for the internet traffic

Comment: In that case, you can try to use Istio and start controlling how the different services communicate with each other, I think that using OpenVPN for communicating services is a stronger solution but not the only one, another option is to use gRPC and mTLS to ensure the communication is protected.